# bundle install to existing rail project gives gem files error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

when running existing ruby on rails project from another machine to my fedora machine. running bundle install command gives following error:

when running: bundle install with gem 'pg', '~> 0.18' in gem file, it says bundle need to install gem install pg -v '0.18' , then running gem install pg -v '0.18' gives following error:

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/aps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/pg-0.21.0/ext
/home/aps/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180626-32726-dfgy1l.rb extconf.rb

checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway.

If building fails, please try again with
--with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h...

Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header

---

These two gems couldn't install :
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18' and gem 'rjb'

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please attached the error log in question?

Answer (score 1):

As per the details shared, it is giving error because the native dependencies of nio4r was installed on some other machine and the same cannot be found on your machine that is why it is showing error:

At first try to install build essentials:

```
sudo dnf install build-essential patch

sudo dnf install libgmp3-dev
```

Now, try running following:

```
bundle install
```

For pg error as shown in the post:

```
sudo dnf install /usr/include/libpq-fe.h
```

If the above command does not work then run

```
sudo dnf install postgresql-devel
```

Comment: after running these commands they says : no match found

but now doing few things updating to same version of ruby as on other system, it now only gives errors for two gems which is listed in gem file.

commenting those gems bundle install and update commands works.

these are : gem 'pg', '~> 0.18' and gem 'rjb'. i am editing and adding error in above main question area. if there is any solution to it?